# Creating a Custom ScrollViewer using WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to create a ScrollViewer with some customizations. Like this:

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Control.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=DynamicUserControl}" />
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="#88ff0000" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DynamicUserControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DynamicUserControl", typeof(object), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object DynamicUserControl
    {
        get { return GetValue(DynamicUserControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DynamicUserControlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

TestForm.xaml (Using the UserControl1):

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.TestForm"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Control"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestForm" Height="200" Width="500">
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource AimDarkGradBg01}">
        <local:UserControl1>
            <local:UserControl1.DynamicUserControl>
                <Button>Click me</Button>
            </local:UserControl1.DynamicUserControl>
        </local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But the problem is no matter what content I put in the `local:UserControl1.DynamicUserControl`, nothing is rendered.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually you binding expression. The correct binding should be like:

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="uc">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <WrapPanel>
                <!-- Dynamic Content -->
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type control:UserControl1}}, Path=DynamicUserControl}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Canvas>
            <!-- Some Code -->
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If you noticed I removed your definition of the template, in which case you don't need it. You can simply just put your code inside the user control.

The other files are correct. Fix what I told you above and you're good to go.

Comment: Ok, I create this example, but when I run the aplication the contentpresenter of the UserControl1 is empty. (And I put thinks inside him).

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi please see addition to my answer.

Comment: Ok I tried again, the ContentPresenter inside the UserControl keeps completely empty. I'm thinking i'm using wpf 4 that has some different behaviors about many things, do you think the version is make this behavior?

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact code you're attempting to compile? The version shouldn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Made changes to final solution.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Your answer really helped, I found what was the problem, so to give you the rightful credit for the answer I updated your answer, to make it right. If you accepted my update I'll mark as correct answer, and we can finish this topic.

Comment: I'm actually surprised using `ElementName` didn't work for you as I've never had an issue binding this way before. Thanks for the update, glad it works now.